What is the best solution to automatically rotate Azure Storage account Access keys in a large scale company?
I work for a big company as a Cloud security engineer and I am wondering what would other companies use to manage the storage accounts access keys auto rotation in Azure.
I find it a little heavy to ask all the storage owners to deploy (event grid, function app) to handle the auto rotation as explained here: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/enable-automatic-secret-rotation-by-triggering-azure-function/ba-p/4055618
It was possible for key vault to directly handle the storage key rotation without additionnal infrastructure but it is marked as (legacy) now : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/overview-storage-keys
Can you share your experiences and your advices for the easiest way to implement auto rotation ?


Manage storage account access keys
Automate the rotation of a secret for resources that use one set of authentication credentials


In fact, the recommendation would be to disable the usage of the access keys. The recommendation would be to use Managed Identities which Azure takes care of the rotation for you.

Plus one to what @ThiagoCustodio said, that is very much the recommendation, keys should not be used unless there are very specific use cases that require those, and those should be storage accounts limited to very specific purposes, such as those backing Azure Functions, not the ones that contain your data and therefore matter much more.
